# 'Else If' giving the error " 'else' without 'if' " in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, if-statement

I'm tring to do some Java coding with NETBEANS 7.1.2, but it gives me the error " 'else' without 'if' " when I try to build this code:

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String search1;
    search1 = jTextField1.getText();

    // stone
    if (search1=="Stone" || search1=="Rock" || search1=="stone" || search1=="rock" || search1=="1");
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Stone: 1");

    }

    // grass
    else if (search1=="Grass" || search1=="grass");
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Grass: 2");
    }



}
```

The problem occurs at the 'else if' under the //grass. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

In this line:

```
if (search1=="Stone" || search1=="Rock" || search1=="stone" || search1=="rock" || search1=="1");
```

And this line:

```
else if (search1=="Grass" || search1=="grass");
```

You must remove the `;` at the end. Those semicolons are misplaced, the compiler will interpret the first `if` statement as an `if` without a body, the code between the `{}` as a block scope and the `else if` statement as an `else` without an `if`.

Also, be aware that all the string comparisons are mistaken, in Java you *must* use `equals()` for comparing two strings for **equality**, not `==`, which compares for **identity**.

Answer (score 2):

You have an ";" after the first condition.

The compiler assume this is the end of if statement, therefore the compiler show error at "else if" line.
Remove the ";" and it should be fine!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Another example of stackoverflow's amazing and helpful community!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem like what u have. 
I found this as solution and it worked fine for me. I guess this is what u need.

```
    String unit=jTextField1.getText();
            if(unit.equals("kg") || unit.equals("gm")){
    // some code
            }
else if(unit.equals("dzn")||unit.equals("qty")){
    // some code
        }
```